# необходимо преобразовать текст из txtin, в котором больше трех пробелов в новый абзац и вставить его в txtout, проблема с вводом-выводом

Tags: javascript

```
function pocan288 () {

   const str = document.getElementsByClassName("txtin")[0].value;
   const parts = str.split('   ');
   const output = parts.(part => `<p>${part}</p>`).join('');
   element value ='txtout';
}



<p> Исходный текст</p>
<textarea class='txtin'>  </textarea> 

<p><input type="submit" onclick="pocan288()"></p>

<p> Текст с абзацами </p>
<textarea class='txtout'>  </textarea>
```

Comment: Ваш код вообще не валидный, что за код такой `parts.(part =>...)` и `element value = 'txtout'`

Answer (score 0):

К примеру такой вариант

```js
function check() {
  const strIn = document.getElementsByClassName("txtin")[0].value;
  const strOut = document.getElementsByClassName("txtout")[0];
  console.log(strIn);
  const parts = strIn.split('   ');
  const output = parts.map(part => `<p>${part}</p>`).join('');
  console.log(output);
  strOut.value = output;
}
```

```html
<p> Исходный текст </p>
<textarea class='txtin'></textarea >

<p><input type="submit" onclick="check();"></p>

<p>Текст с абзацами </p>
<textarea class='txtout'></textarea>
```

Comment: Благодарен за помощь. Для того, чтобы программа корректно работала, необходимо изменить код на: const output = parts.join('\n');

Comment: Я лишь сделал её работоспособной, то как вам нужно её преобразовать, ваше дело. Хорошего коддинга!